# Swift - Check if a value belongs is in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array of type "User" and I would like to check if a value belongs to a property type.
My code :

```
   struct User: Identifiable {
        
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var age: String
    }

    var array: User = [
        User[name: "AZE", age: "10"]
        User[name: "QSD", age: "37"]
    ]
```

For example I'd like to know if "AZE" belongs to the property array "name". What is the function for retrieving this information. I hope you understood my problem and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `array`s define with `[Type]` like `[User]`

Second of all `init` method calls as with `(Arguments)` like `User(name: ,age:)`

And last but not least, don't forget the ',' between elements of the array.

So

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var age: String
}

var array: [User] = [
    User(name: "AZE", age: "10"),
    User(name: "QSD", age: "37")
]
```

So now you can check your element inside with `contains` like

```
array.contains(where: { user in user.name == "AZE" }) // returns `true` if it is
```

## Tips

Try name `array`s not **array**. Use plural names instead like `users`

---

#### To returtning the found one:

```
users.first(where: { user in user.name == "AZE" })
```

---

#### To summarizing it

```
users.first { $0.name == "AZE" }
```

Comment: If now I want to retrieve this object with only access to the "name", for example to create a new variable, do you have an idea on how to proceed ?

Comment: You should use `users.first(where: { user in user.name == "AZE" })`